Flutter deployed web firebase hosting
I have Published my flutter web firebase hosting, i have got this error on deployed web while i am adding data to the firebase:

minified:IW not found you need to call get.put(minified:IW()) or Get.lazyPut(() => ProductController());

I am trying to add data to my firebase database, on my deployed website

If you need the controller immediately use Get.put() instead of Get.lazyPut().
like  Get.lazyPut(() => ProductController()); into Get.put(ProductController());
if still getting same issue than edit question and add some code so it's easy to understand you problem

Thanks... it Fixed, but i have got another error not in deployed web, in my local project..

the error(../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_dropzone_web-3.0.13/lib/flutter_dropzone_plugin.dart:64:25: Error: The return type of the method 'FlutterDropzonePlugin.pickFiles' is 'Future<List>', which does not match the return type, 'Future<List>', of the overridden method, 'FlutterDropzonePlatform.pickFiles'.

'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
'List' is from 'dart:core'.)
^


can you please share some code so it's easy to understand, what is exactly error is
